# Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$and'

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to run two filters for counting the number of male and females in my table. I was already able to filter and count either male or females on my table with

```
db.employee.aggregate({$match:{"gender":"male"}},{$count:"Males"})
```

or

```
db.employee.aggregate({$match:{"gender":"female"}},{$count:"Females"})
```

Now, I was just trying to combine this two commands into one single command. How is it done in Mongodb with $and ?, I have the following code

```
db.employee.aggregate(
 { $and : 
 [  
 {$match:{"gender":"male"}},{$count:"Males"}
 ,
 {$match:{"gender":"female"}},{$count:"Females"}
 ]
 }   
 )
```

and its throwing this error:

```
E QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$and'",
    "code" : 40324,
    "codeName" : "Location40324"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:536:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:620:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:260:9
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1062:12
@(shell):1:1
```

What did I do wrong here though?, alredy look on the mondodb documenations, still can't determine why it is erroring out.

I'm following this syntax format based on the documentation though.

```
db.<collection_name>.aggregate({
 $and : [
 { <condition1>} , {condition2}
 ]
 } )
```

My Database contents could be created with the ff. script.:

```
db.employee.insert([
    {"id":"1","name": "Ricardo Carpio","age": 24, "gender": "male", "birthYear" : "1995" , "hobby" : "Reading books"},
    {"id":"2","name": "Alice Salpicao","age": 27, "gender": "female", "birthYear" : "1992" , "hobby" : "Eating"},
    {"id":"3","name": "Cardo Agustin","age": 25, "gender": "male", "birthYear" : "1996" , "hobby" : "Jogging"},
    {"id":"5","name": "Gamora Yuchi","age": 24, "gender": "female", "birthYear" : "1995" , "hobby" : "Singing"},
    {"id":"6","name": "Thanos Pink","age": 29, "gender": "male", "birthYear" : "1990" , "hobby" : "Collecting gems"}
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `[]` in the aggregation.
Use `db.employee.aggregate([])` instead of `db.employee.aggregate()`

Try with this

```
employee.aggregate([
{
$group:{
    _id:"$gender",
    count:{$sum:1}
    }
}
])
```

As per your requirement, that you need the field names as Male and Female try with this one.

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([
{
$facet:{
    male:[        
            {$match:{gender:"Male"}},
            {$count:"Male"}
    ],
    female:[        
            {$match:{gender:"Female"}},
            {$count:"Female"}
    ]

    }
},
{
$unwind:{
    path:"$male",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true
    }
},
{
$unwind:{
    path:"$female",
    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true
    }
},
{
$project:{
    Male:{$ifNull:["$male.Male",0]},
    Female:{$ifNull:["$female.Female",0]}
    }
}
])
```

Comment: Thanks it working too, but, is it possible to preserve the labeling of the results?. It just that I dont want to have the generic unique values of the gender as label that also includes the _id, rather... have it as Male Count: <number> & Female Count: <number>. I already have this working that way, but I can't just make it work as one command. My original script would give me { "Males" : 3 } for males and same with females, but this one is giving me additional properties i dont need with result for male like this .. { "_id" : "male", "count" : 3 }

Comment: Can't clear. Do you mean, getting the ids of the user for male and females?

Comment: Nope. I wanted to have a much cleaner output of the count by just having the Female Count : <Number> and Male Count : <number> instead of generic results from group which just count the number of unique values in the table and also outputs it same unique value as label on the result instead of a customized label.

Comment: db.employee.aggregate({$match:{"gender":"male"}},{$count:"Male Count: "})...
was my code for the single command...So it would give me "{Male Count: 2}" as a result and where Male Count is the label. not the unique value male that also outputs a tad bit of a generic result with _id: "male" , count: 3... something like that. I was trying to do it with $and, but I believe I am already following the correct syntax, based on the documentation, but it seems I missed something else still.

Comment: You need Male or Female label instead of Label count , Is it right?

Comment: Yes, as that would be cleaner.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check it.

Comment: Thanks, its working now as I wanted it. Although I don't know what the other syntax was for, will just search for it. Thanks again.